# Moving two composite ROI's at once within ImageJ Macro

Tags: imagej, imagej-macro

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LYyr.png)I have two composite ROI's which correspond to two parts of the body that I'd like to pin together to move around an image before I save them in their new location. They need to be moved the same amount, so need to be pinned together. I cannot use the OR function, as they cannot be split back into two individual ROI's, but instead split into their 50 or so smaller parts.

All this needs to be doable within a macro, so that the user can just drag the pair of composite ROI's across the anatomy.

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: It would be easier to understand if you could add some illustrations of what you would like to do. It's very difficult to imagine what your idea is right now.

Comment: Also, you might get better answers by asking on [forum.image.sc](https://forum.image.sc/), the official forum for ImageJ and other scientific image processing. In case you cross-post there, please link here so that the discussion stays transparent.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! I can't directly illustrate this as it is using patient information - please find my terrible paint drawing. If you imagine in red is one composite ROI and in blue is another composite ROI. The kidney anatomy outlined in these images sometimes moves, and so I need to be able to drag the ROI's outlining this anatomy to a new location, while keeping them in the same orientation and distance from each other. 

If I use the "OR" function, and then later split them up, it splits into all the individual ROI's, instead of back into the two composite ones. Hope this helps!